# Eclipse not finding phone

Tags: android, android-emulator

Help.

I recently purchased a new PC. I had my eclipse set up and running for about a year no problem. But now with my new PC, Eclipse does not recognize my phone. My Phone is in Debug mode. When I plug the phone into the computer, it does connect. However Eclipse does not find it.

In the Android Device Chooser, my phone is not listed as an option to pick.

Any ideas?

Comment: What OS are you running? It's very hard to help with so few details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are using Windows? I suppose you need the USB driver so that the OS can recognize your phone in debug mode. See:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html

http://developer.android.com/sdk/oem-usb.html

Comment: Yes...thanks. I had to go to HTC and download the latest drivers. problem solved. Thanks

Comment: @Stephen McClendon, you can also choose my answer as the selected answer by clicking the empty tick mark next to my answer.